# Python - Classes and OOP Basics

Tags: python, oop

I do not fully understand classes.  I have read the python documentation and several other tutorials.  I get the basic gist of it but don't understand the nuance.  For instance in my code here:

```
class whiteroom():
    """ Pick a door: red, blue, green, or black. """

    do = raw_input("> ")

    if "red" in do:
        print "You entered the red room."

    elif "blue" in do:
        print "You entered the blue room."

    elif "green" in do:
        print "You entered the green room."

    elif "black" in do:
        print "You entered the black room."

    else:
        print "You sit patiently but slowly begin to stave.  You're running out of time."
        return whiteroom()

game = whiteroom()
game
```

(original [codepad](http://codepad.org/IP8IpfOl))

I would like to return the class whiteroom.  Which is, either not possible, or not being done correctly.  If you could clear up how to return a class or how to "link" two classes together so that whiteroom repeats on the else and the other rooms (which would be classes) are returned when called that would be awesome.

Also I'm super shaky on `__init__` and am still not really sure what its purpose is.  Everyone keeps telling me that it "initializes", which I'm sure it does, but that doesn't seem to be helping my brain out.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Functions are very different from classes. It looks like you took a function and just changed the `def` to `class`. I guess that *mostly* works in your case, but it's not how classes are supposed to go.

Classes contain functions (methods) and data. For example, you have a ball:

```
class Ball(object):
    # __init__ is a special method called whenever you try to make
    # an instance of a class. As you heard, it initializes the object.
    # Here, we'll initialize some of the data.
    def __init__(self):
        # Let's add some data to the [instance of the] class.
        self.position = (100, 100)
        self.velocity = (0, 0)

    # We can also add our own functions. When our ball bounces,
    # its vertical velocity will be negated. (no gravity here!)
    def bounce(self):
        self.velocity = (self.velocity[0], -self.velocity[1])
```

Now we have a `Ball` class. How can we use it?

```
>>> ball1 = Ball()
>>> ball1
<Ball object at ...>
```

It doesn't look very useful. The data is where it could be useful:

```
>>> ball1.position
(100, 100)
>>> ball1.velocity
(0, 0)
>>> ball1.position = (200, 100)
>>> ball1.position
(200, 100)
```

Alright, cool, but what's the advantage over a global variable? If you have another `Ball` instance, it will remain independent:

```
>>> ball2 = Ball()
>>> ball2.velocity = (5, 10)
>>> ball2.position
(100, 100)
>>> ball2.velocity
(5, 10)
```

And `ball1` remains independent:

```
>>> ball1.velocity
(0, 0)
```

Now what about that `bounce` method (function in a class) we defined?

```
>>> ball2.bounce()
>>> ball2.velocity
(5, -10)
```

The `bounce` method caused it to modify the `velocity` data of itself. Again, `ball1` was not touched:

```
>>> ball1.velocity
```

## Application

A ball is neat and all, but most people aren't simulating that. You're making a game. Let's think of what kinds of things we have:

- **A room** is the most obvious thing we could have.

So let's make a room. Rooms have names, so we'll have some data to store that:

```
class Room(object):
    # Note that we're taking an argument besides self, here.
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name  # Set the room's name to the name we got.
```

And let's make an instance of it:

```
>>> white_room = Room("White Room")
>>> white_room.name
'White Room'
```

Spiffy. This turns out not to be all that useful if you want different rooms to have different functionality, though, so let's make a *subclass*. A *subclass* inherits all functionality from its *superclass*, but you can add more functionality or override the superclass's functionality.

Let's think about what we want to do with rooms:

> We want to interact with rooms.

And how do we do that?

> The user types in a line of text that gets responded to.

How it's responded do depends on the room, so let's make the room handle that with a method called `interact`:

```
class WhiteRoom(Room):  # A white room is a kind of room.
    def __init__(self):
        # All white rooms have names of 'White Room'.
        self.name = 'White Room'

    def interact(self, line):
        if 'test' in line:
            print "'Test' to you, too!"
```

Now let's try interacting with it:

```
>>> white_room = WhiteRoom()  # WhiteRoom's __init__ doesn't take an argument (even though its superclass's __init__ does; we overrode the superclass's __init__)
>>> white_room.interact('test')
'Test' to you, too!
```

Your original example featured moving between rooms. Let's use a global variable called `current_room` to track which room we're in.<sup>1</sup> Let's also make a red room.

<sup>1. There's better options besides global variables here, but I'm going to use one for simplicity.</sup>

```
class RedRoom(Room):  # A red room is also a kind of room.
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Red Room'

    def interact(self, line):
        global current_room, white_room
        if 'white' in line:
            # We could create a new WhiteRoom, but then it
            # would lose its data (if it had any) after moving
            # out of it and into it again.
            current_room = white_room
```

Now let's try that:

```
>>> red_room = RedRoom()
>>> current_room = red_room
>>> current_room.name
'Red Room'
>>> current_room.interact('go to white room')
>>> current_room.name
'White Room'
```

**Exercise for the reader:** Add code to `WhiteRoom`'s `interact` that allows you to go back to the red room.

Now that we have everything working, let's put it all together. With our new `name` data on all rooms, we can also show the current room in the prompt!

```
def play_game():
    global current_room
    while True:
        line = raw_input(current_room.name + '> ')
        current_room.interact(line)
```

You might also want to make a function to reset the game:

```
def reset_game():
    global current_room, white_room, red_room
    white_room = WhiteRoom()
    red_room = RedRoom()
    current_room = white_room
```

Put all of the class definitions and these functions into a file and you can play it at the prompt like this (assuming they're in `mygame.py`):

```
>>> import mygame
>>> mygame.reset_game()
>>> mygame.play_game()
White Room> test
'Test' to you, too!
White Room> go to red room
Red Room> go to white room
White Room>
```

To be able to play the game just by running the Python script, you can add this at the bottom:

```
def main():
    reset_game()
    play_game()

if __name__ == '__main__':  # If we're running as a script...
    main()
```

And that's a basic introduction to classes and how to apply it to your situation.

Comment: That `Ball` shouldn't be a class. Rule of thumb: If it has only two methods, one of which is `__init__`, you should use a function and `functools.partial` to bind the function to some data. Same for the other classes presented here. Python is not Java! The only thing I see here that *should* be a class is the game itself, for which you use module-global state instead?

Comment: In the user exercise portion I tried to make it possible to go from white room to red room.  But I cannot.  I added "if "x" in line: current_room = red_room"  The current room variable does not change.  However if I do something like: "if "x" in line: print "this"" it works.  Thank you for your post.  It was super helpful!

Comment: @Niklas: Yes; the game state really *should* be in a class; I was trying to make it as simple as possible, however, and I felt that making the game state a class might make my answer more confusing. Secondly, perhaps some of these things should not have been classes, but given that I was trying to demonstrate how to use classes, I think it was reasonable to use them. Besides, I think someone could think of other methods and data to add to the classes.

Comment: @icktoofay: Yep, I think you have a point :) +1 for a long and very detailed explanation.

Answer (score 7):

I'm sure you've heard all this before, but I'll give it a go.

Classes are a way to group up a bunch of function and variables into a single object. When you get all the way down to it, this is simply a way of organizing everything into groups that make sense. There are benefits down the road for making things easier to understand, debug, extend, or maintain, but basically its just a way to make something more defined in your mental model.

Your code looks like you are trying to write your entire program inside an 'object' (really, you just have an incorrectly written function).

Consider this instead.

Think of your mental model of rooms which have doors to them and whiteboards in them. Doors have a color. Also, whiteboards can have some text written on them. We'll leave it there to be simple.

To me, this suggests 3 different objects -- a door object that has a string for color, a whiteboard object that has a string for the text, and a room object that has a door and a whiteboard.

Consider the following code:

```
class Door(object):
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color

class Whiteboard(object):
    def __init__(self, default_text=''):
        self.text = ''
        self.write_text(default_text)

    def write_text(self, text):
        self.text += text

    def erase(self):
        self.text = ''


class Room(object):
    def __init__(self, doorcolor, whiteboardtext=''):
        self.whiteboard = Whiteboard(whiteboardtext)
        self.door = Door(doorcolor)




# make a room with a red door and no text on the whiteboard
room1 = Room('red')

# make a room with a blue door and 'yeah, whiteboard' on the whiteboard
room2 = Room('blue', 'yeah, whiteboard')

# make a room with a green door
room3 = Room('green')



# now I can play around with my 'rooms' and they keep track of everything internally

print 'room 1 door color: ' + room1.door.color
print 'room 2 door color: ' + room2.door.color


# all my rooms have a door and a whiteboard, but each one is different and self contained. For example
# if I write on room 1's whiteboard, it doesn't change anything about room 3s

print 'room1 whiteboard: ' + room1.whiteboard.text
print 'room2 whiteboard: ' + room2.whiteboard.text
print 'room3 whiteboard: ' + room3.whiteboard.text

print '-- changeing room 1 whiteboard text --'

room1.whiteboard.write_text('oop is really helpful')


print 'room1 whiteboard: ' + room1.whiteboard.text
print 'room2 whiteboard: ' + room2.whiteboard.text
print 'room3 whiteboard: ' + room3.whiteboard.text
```

The **init** function is what gets called when you 'initialize' a new instance of your class. In the example I am making 3 Room objects which each create a Door and Whiteboard object internally. The parameters I pass into the constructor `Room(parameter1, parameter2)` get passed to the **init** functions - you can see I'm using this to set the door color and optionally some text on the whiteboard. Also notice that the variables that 'belong' to the objects are referenced with `self` - this reference is what gets passed in as the first parameter to all class functions (and becomes more important later when you are extending classes and other more advanced things).

Answer (score 3):

In OOP you have types and objects. Types are abstractions (I would call it *idea of*) and concrete objects. When you define a class via the syntax `class Idea:` you identify a type and you can give that type attributes and abilities.

For example:

```
class Idea:
    populare = None

    @staticmethod
    def change_the_world(atrribute):
        return f'a new {attribute} world'
```

Why is it great and not just a coding style? Just because, in our complex world there are many ideas and even more of the *idea of* those ideas and so it appears in complex applications. You can have the idea itself as a basement, a mix of other ideas, as a layer in multiple levels of ideas or a hybrid of all that.

As an example:

```
class Idea:
    populare = None

    @staticmethod
    def change_the_world(atrribute):
        return f'a new {attribute} world'

class Freedom(Idea):
    populare = True

    @classmethod
    def desire(cls):
        return cls.change_the_world('free')
```

How powerful this is? You will notice when you think about [built-in-types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) and what all you have done or could do with them. How easy it gets to implement [design pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/what-is-pattern) and to built a whole world that manifests your point of view. But enough of types, there are a concrete objects. They are manifested types with individual identities, so called Entity's.

As example:

```
class Color:

    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = None
        self.value = None

    def less_red(self):
        red_portion = self.value[0]
        new_value = red_portion-1
        self.value = (new_value, self.value[1], self.value[2])
        return self.value

my_red = Color('My Red', (255, 0, 0))
```

Entities can be imagine as manifested idea, that can be identified by themselves. That why the we usually write `self` as the first parameter in the `__init__` it is a hint that this pointer is a reference to itself, not the class but the entity you just initialized.

[Another try and example in context with `super()` and tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74065727/13629335)

Answer (score 2):

You're really far off.

Sorry to say it, but this is just barely salvageable.

From what I can tell you want something like a room class, for instance:

```
class Room(object):
    ''' A generic room '''
    def __init__(self):
        self.choices = None
        self.enter()
    def enter(self):
        ''' Enter the room, to be filled out in subclass '''
        pass
    def print_choices(self):
        '''You are stuck bro'''
        print "You are stuck bro"
```

Then you can make a specific room like the whiteroom like so:

```
class Whiteroom(Room):
    ''' A white room '''
    def __init__(self):
        self.choices = ["red", "blue", "green", "black"]
        self.enter()
    def enter(self):
        print "You sit patiently, but slowly begin to starve.  You're running out of time."
    def print_choices(self):
        print "You can choose from the following rooms:"
        print self.choices

class Blackroom(Room):
    ''' A black room '''
    def enter(self):
        print "It's really dark in here.  You're out of time."

class Redroom(Room):
    ''' A red room '''
    def __init__(self):
        self.choices = ["black", "blue", "green", "white"]
        self.enter()
    def enter(self):
        print "It's getting hot in here.  So take off all your clothes."
    def print_choices(self):
        print "You can choose from the following rooms:"
        print self.choices

class Blueroom(Room):
    ''' A blue room '''
    def __init__(self):
        self.choices = ["black", "red", "green", "white"]
        self.enter()
    def enter(self):
        print "It's nice and cool in here.  Stay awhile if you want."
    def print_choices(self):
        print "You can choose from the following rooms:"
        print self.choices

class Greenroom(Room):
    ''' A green room '''
    def __init__(self):
        self.choices = ["black", "red", "blue", "white"]
        self.enter()
    def enter(self):
        print "You won."
```

Then you'd have do this to run the game:

```
print "Type 'quit' to quit"
print "Type 'choices' to see what your choices are"

current_room = Whiteroom()
done = False
while (not done):
    entry = raw_input("> ")
    if entry == "quit":
        done = True
    if "choices" in entry:
        current_room.print_choices()
    if current_room.choices:
        if entry in current_room.choices:    
            if "white" in entry:
                current_room = Whiteroom()

            if "black" in entry:
                current_room = Blackroom()

            if "red" in entry:
                current_room = Redroom()

            if "green" in entry:
                current_room = Greenroom()
                done = True

            if "blue" in entry:
                current_room = Blueroom()
```

That's my best attempt at turning your snippet into an actual game, using classes.

Answer (score -1):

class Circle():

```
pi = 3.14

def __init__(self,radius=1):
    
    self.radius = radius
    self.area = radius*radius*self.pi

def get_circrumference(self):
    return self.radius* self.pi*2
```

result:
Circle(23)

my_circle = Circle(30)

my_circle.pi =
3.14

my_circle.radius =
30

my_circle.get_circrumference() =
118.4

my_circle.area =
2826.0

help(Circle) =
Help on class Circle in module **main**:

class Circle(builtins.object)
|  Circle(radius=1)
|
|  Methods defined here:
|
|  **init**(self, radius=1)
|      Initialize self.  See help(type(self)) for accurate signature.
|
|  get_circrumference(self)
|
|  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Data descriptors defined here:
|
|  **dict**
|      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
|
|  **weakref**
|      list of weak references to the object (if defined)
|
|  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Data and other attributes defined here:
|
|  pi = 3.14

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simple implementation of cartesian points using class:

```
class Point:

        def __init__(self, x, y):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y

        def move(self, move_x, move_y):
            self.x += move_x
            self.y += move_y

        def scale(self, factor):
            self.x *= factor
            self.y *= factor

        def mod(self):
            return (self.x ** 2 + self.y ** 2) ** (1 / 2)
```

`A = Point(3, 4)`

`print(A.x, A.y)` -> `3 4`

`print(A.mod())` -> `5`

```
A.move(2, 8)   #(5, 12)
A.scale(2)     #(10, 26)
```