# What are python classes?

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn programming and came across this in my core app.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
# Create your views here.

class SplashView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "index.html"
```

What specifically does the above class do, in this context?

Comment: Did you even try searching for yourself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - Classes and OOP Basics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004850/python-classes-and-oop-basics)

Comment: This is not a good example for a beginner; this particular class is part of the Django framework and, as such, cannot be understood on its own, but rather in how the framework uses such a class.

Answer (score 4):

It does everything `TemplateView` does, plus has an attribute called "template_name" with the value of "index.html".