# How Do I For loop With A Dict in Python That Is In Another Class

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

For example if I were using a list i would say

```
for i in taskList:
   Print('item')
```

I was wondering how to do this with a dict also this dict is in another class. I have a class set up for the user to input tasks which adds it to a dict (this works) however now I want another class that pulls from the dict in the first class. is this possible? Here is a short example of what I've tried

```
class TaskList():
   itemsToDoDic = {'Cleaning' : 0, 'Cook' :0}


classItems = TaskList()

class Importance():
   classItems.itemsToDoDic
   def levelOfImportance(self):
      for i in self.ClassItems.itemsToDoDic:
         importanceValue = int(input('Enter a 
         number 1 - 5')
```

I got the following errors:

1. Instance of 'Importance' has no 'ClassItems' member
2. Unused variable 'i'
3. Unused variable 'importanceValue'

Comment: refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004850/python-classes-and-oop-basics

Comment: note your `itemsToDoDic` is a class variable and not an instance variable. you should assign to `self.itemsToDoDic`, or use via `TaskList.itemsToDoDic`

Comment: Did you mean: `for i in classItems.itemsToDoDic:` ?

Comment: @JaydeepDevda Hey, thanks for the reply but this didnt help in my situation

Comment: @quamrana yes, I tried that at first than the self one but I keep getting the unused variable in the for loop for "i"

Comment: Yes, but `self.ClassItems` is an error and your program won't run. The others are just warnings. Did you mean: `for _ in classItems.itemsToDoDic:` ?

Answer (score 1):

Say you have two classes, needless to say, that if your source class (the one you get the dict from) is in another file, you will have to import it.

Check this code:

```
# this is the source class
class DictContainingClass():
  itemsToDoDic = {'Cleaning' : 0, 'Cook' :0}

# creating an instance of the source class
instance = DictContainingClass()

# this is the taking class
class DictNeedingClass():

  
  # creating your class method:
  def myClassMethod(self):

    # accessing the dict inside it
    getDict = instance.itemsToDoDic
  
    # now looping through its items
    for item in getDict.items():
      print(item)
    # or if you want to access only the keys
    for key in getDict.keys():
      print(key)
    # or if you want to access only values
    for value in getDict.values():
      print(value)

# calling for your method
DictNeedingClass().myClassMethod()
```

Hope this answered your question, please refer to this [dictionary methods page](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_dictionary.asp) for more information.

Comment: Thank you so much! This actually helped and the code works now! I honestly have been stuck on this for awhile. Appreciate you taking the time out of your day to help solve this and reply fast, means a lot!

Comment: @SpacedOutKID This is my first time I contribute to the community, I myself am new to coding. This is encouraging, good luck on your journey. Please consider checking this thread as answered if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to your error.

Here in for loop `for i in self.ClassItems.itemsToDoDic:` you are calling `self.ClassItems.itemsToDoDic` which is not defined in `Importance` class rather defined as a global variable.

```
class TaskList():
   itemsToDoDic = {'Cleaning' : 0, 'Cook' :0}

classItems = TaskList()

class Importance():
    def levelOfImportance(self):
        for key,value in classItems.itemsToDoDic.items():
            print(key,value)
            #Rest of your code here

#testing
Importance().levelOfImportance()
```

Check this page if you want to know more about for loop over the dictionary variable.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterate-over-a-dictionary-in-python/

Comment: Hey, thanks for commenting, I tried this but it says that it is not callable

Comment: can you paste error here? and before commenting, the error makes sure your code does not have any typo error.