# How do you program collision in classes?

Tags: python, class, pygame, collision-detection

I've been having a hard time getting collision to work. I'm new and don't know the in and outs with coding so please can you explain your reasoning.

Here's a simple of some code:

```
def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, sprite):
    self.x = player_x
    self.y = player_y
    self.width = player.width
    self.height = player.height
    self.col = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, sprite)
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

def velocity_player(self):
    player_vertical_velocity = 0
    player_horizontal_velocity = 0
    player_y = player_y + player_vertical_velocity
    player_x = player_x + player_horizontal_velocity
    player_fr = 5

def render(self):
    player_surface = pygame.image.load("Bunny.png")
    player_surface.set_colorkey(TRANSPARENT_GREEN)

    player_left = pygame.image.load("Bunny_left.png")
    player_left.set_colorkey(TRANSPARENT_GREEN)

    player_left = pygame.image.load("Bunny_left.png")
    player_left.set_colorkey(TRANSPARENT_GREEN)

    player_fall = pygame.image.load("Bunny_Fall.png")
    player_fall.set_colorkey(TRANSPARENT_GREEN)
    
    player_jump = pygame.image.load("Bunny_r_Jump.png")
    screen.blit(player_surface, [player_x, player_y])
```

Comment: Just messed around with your code, and I got a question. You use ```get.rect``` to get the rectangle of an image right?

Comment: Also, I want to use classes to print multiple enemies on the screen at once, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

First, start by learning the concept of [Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) (see also [Python - Classes and OOP Basics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004850/python-classes-and-oop-basics)). The collision must be detected in every frame. Usually you don't want to do it in the constrictor of a class. See [How do I detect collision in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640685/how-do-i-detect-collision-in-pygame/65064907#65064907).

When using [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`s](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) and [`pygame.sprite.Group`s](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group), collision is detected by functions like [`pygame.sprite.spritecollide()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide) and [`pygame.sprite.groupcollide()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide). However, collision detection is usually not performed in the Sprite class. This is done in the outer code that manages the Sprites and the interaction between the Sprites.

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((250, 250))

class RectSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, x, y, w, h):
        super().__init__() 
        self.image = pygame.Surface((w, h))
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, w, h)

player = RectSprite((255, 0, 0), 0, 0, 50, 50)
obstacle1 = RectSprite((128, 128, 128), 50, 150, 50, 50)
obstacle2 = RectSprite((128, 128, 128), 150, 50, 50, 50)
all_group = pygame.sprite.Group([obstacle1, obstacle2, player])
obstacle_group = pygame.sprite.Group([obstacle1, obstacle2])

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    player.rect.center = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    collide = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, obstacle_group, False)
    
    window.fill(0)
    all_group.draw(window)
    for s in collide:
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 255, 255), s.rect, 5, 1)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```